# Spring Boot + JAX-WS without an extra servlet?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cxf, jax-ws

I'm working on migrating some applications from Spring to Spring Boot. Some of the applications provide SOAP web services on the root url of the application (`/`), which is fine with a Spring application. But on Spring Boot, this causes some issues, since setting up a servlet to listen on `/` will overwrite the default dispatcher-servlet, causing for instance the actuator endpoint to be overwritten. Still, I do not want to change the url to my wsdl, since this will lead to updating all the clients of the service.

Is there a way to have Spring Boot supply a JAX-WS/CXF Web Service on `/`, without overwriting the default servlet? Is there a way to have the default servlet supply the web service, without the need of an extra `CXFServlet`?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to access the wsdl at least, by exposing the `CXFServlet` as a filter, rather than a servlet:

```
@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint(final SpringBus springBus, final MyServiceImpl myService) {
    final EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus, myService);
    endpoint.publish("/MyService");
    return endpoint;
}

@Bean
public SpringBus springBus() {
    return new SpringBus();
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<CXFServlet> cxfServletFilter(final SpringBus springBus) {
    final CXFServlet cxfServlet = new CXFServlet();
    cxfServlet.setBus(springBus);
    final FilterRegistrationBean<CXFServlet> filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(cxfServlet);

    filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(2);

    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

I also removed `cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws` from my pom.xml.

Any feedback on this solution is appreciated.